# Can i have a user defined value as a data type in json in golang

Tags: json, go

I am creating a json response in golang.I have a question that i am able to generate a json such as :

```
{
  "Name" : "Country",
  "Value" : "abc"
}
```

The value of name and value can change based on the user and the struct I am using is like:

```
type xAxis struct {
  Name string,
  Value string
}
```

I want my json to look like this:

```
{
   "Country" : "abc"
}
```

Is it possible to create the json like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can override the way Go's json package marshals a struct by writing a custom `MarshalJSON` function:

```
type xAxis struct {
    Name  string
    Value string
}

func (a xAxis) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{a.Name: a.Value})
}
```

to try it: http://play.golang.org/p/G_E4IpNYIz

Answer (score 0):

The `encoding/json` package allows you to use a map instead of a struct.

That's probably not as performant as structures, but it works.

```
data := map[string]string {
    "Country": "abc",
    "Foo": "bar",
}

// Creating JSON from a map
j, err := json.Marshal(data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(j))
// ==> {"Country":"abc","Foo":"bar"}

// Creating map from JSON
var data2 map[string]string
err = json.Unmarshal(j, &data2)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(data2)
// ==> map[Country:abc Foo:bar]
```